# python opencv dll load failed Missing environment variables?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, python-3.x

I want to use Blender 2.72b with OpenCV, so I had to build it for Python3 (I have 3.4.2 installed since Blender is using that too). I'm working on Win7 64bit, so I used a 64bit version of Python and [NumPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) (Blender too of course). For OpenCV I used 3.0.0-beta.

For building I used CMake 2.8 and Visual Studio 2010 Professional (since I have a student-license > Visual Studio 10 Win64 in CMake).
I followed [these](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html) instructions (lower ones), modified for python3.

These are my folders:
Target build-folder for CMake (OpenCV.sln executed and build in here too of course):

```
C:\Users\Gunnar\Desktop\build\
```

OpenCV-source-folder:

```
C:\Users\Gunnar\Downloads\opencv\sources\
```

Python installed here:

```
C:\Python34\
```

The build went fine, I adjusted the following before generating with CMake (python2 left blank):

```
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE          -> C:/Python34/python.exe
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR         -> C:/Python34/include
PYTHON3_LIBRARY             -> C:/Python34/libs/python34.lib
PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS  -> C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH       -> C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages
BUILD_opencv_python3        -> true
```

The build-folder has a cv2.pyd at

```
C:\Users\Gunnar\Desktop\build\lib\Release\
```

The cv2.pyd got copied to

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\
```

automatically and I copied it to

```
M:\Programme\blender-2.72b-windows64\2.72\python\lib\site-packages\
```

If I now open the python IDLE, I get the following error (same in Blender of course):

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

(in english: DLL load failed: Module not found.)

I'm assuming that I'm missing environment variables (from what I've found googling for it).

Looking into them I have no corresponding entry for PATH and no PYTHONPATH.

My problem now is that I don't know what I need to set there. I never really had to change something in there and I don't know what exactly is needed.

If more information are needed let me know.

EDIT:
I got i working now. I'm not quite sure, which one it did in the end, but I first used

```
cmd > setx -m OPENCV_DIR C:\Users\Gunnar\Desktop\build
```

and than edited the PATH-variable with these:

```
C:\Users\Gunnar\Desktop\build;
C:\Users\Gunnar\Desktop\build\lib\Release;
C:\Users\Gunnar\Desktop\build\x64\Release;
C:\Users\Gunnar\Desktop\build\bin\Release
```

And right now it works even though I removed all of them...

Comment: unless you did a 'static' build of the opencv libs, the cv2.pyd will be still dependant on the opencv dlls, those have to be found ('be on the PATH') at runtime.

Comment: @berak Ok, so I need a PATH-var for the folder ...\bin\Release? This is the one the dlls are in.

Comment: most probably you do need that